# Fill_Rect in SDL

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, sdl

I got some question for SDL_FillRect.

normally the function work like that:
SDL_FillRect(screen, &screen->clip_rect, color);

My question is, instead of passing a single color, can I fill up my Rect with multiple color which contain different Red, blue, and green channel of pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you go about determining the color pattern? I think the closest you are gonna get is with `SDL_BlitSurface`. Pattern a surface and then blit it onto another surface.

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlblitsurface.html

Comment: I actually decode the pixel from video file, which my pixel look like:
[red][green][blue][red][green][blue] and so on.. and the pixel is human non-readable code.